# Can reference system in Leaflet be changed without disrupting data position?

Tags: leaflet, coordinate-system

I have a leaflet map that uses default CRS (EPSG3857) with multiple markers placed on it. Their LatLng are read from JSON file. I want to change map CRS to Simple, keeping markers on exact same screen positions they were.

Now I am not sure how to achieve this. I tried messing around with Leaflet ICRS methods (latLngToPoint, pointToLatLng, project) but without much success. Is this achievable in Leaflet itself or do I need to use external scripts to reproject the data? Changing to CRS.Simple is one time thing, I just need to modify existing data to stay visually the same on new CRS.

Using Leaflet 0.7.7

Answer (score 1):

No. Leaflet does not implement fancy reprojection.

You will have better luck if you manually reproject your data from EPSG:4326 into EPSG:3857, and then use the EPSG:3857 coordinates into a Leaflet map with CRS.Simple.

My tool of choice for reprojections is ogr2ogr, although you can do it in javascript only by using proj4js.